# amazon scraping and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from amazon pages.

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}

r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=smartphone&pg='+str(pageNo)+'?ie=UTF8&pg='+str(pageNo), headers=headers)

content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features='lxml')
```

this function is called for each page.

Everything is scraped fine, i.e. product name, price, etc.

BUT there are a lot of duplicates. If I scrape for example 10 pages, more than 50% of the data is a duplicate.
I guess that, same as when you hit refresh on an amazon page, products are moved based on some internal criteria.
Same applies to my script.
Each time the function is called and the page opened and scraped, the items could have been moved in the meantime from other pages, and so here are the duplicates.

Any idea on how to avoid this?
thanks

Edit: i add more info. I'm   already removing duplicates, but it looks so inefficient scrape dozens of pages and get so few results. Maybe there is a way to read the pages all at once to avoid il,or something similar..

Comment: Can you just strip out the duplicates based on a unique identifier? It's not clear what kind of solution you're looking for here, or what you've tried thus far & where you're getting stuck in that attempt.

Comment: @esqe sure I'm already removing duplicates. But not very efficient in my opinion. I added more info in the post